# Catch an external URL error in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, timeout

Part of my script contacts Twitters api to get the number of shares:

```
twitter = JSON.parse(open("http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.jsonurl=TheURL).read)
```

My concern is if Twitter is down or slow, it will stop my site from working as an error is returned.

How can I catch the error or even set a short timeout so I can skip the call if it's taking too long?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a good idea to connect to Twitter in AJAX request. If you want to get timeout after some seconds then you have [Timeout](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) module in Ruby.

Comment: Ajax is the best solution in this instance - thought of that after I wrote the question, however, for now I've used a begin/rescue block to stop any errors - however, it won't prevent long timeouts if Twitter's server is slow